# How to resolve <not counted> problem in perf tool?

Tags: linux, profile, perf

```
perf stat -d ./sample.out
```

Output is:

```
Performance counter stats for './sample.out':

          0.586266 task-clock (msec)         #    0.007 CPUs utilized          
                 2 context-switches          #    0.003 M/sec                  
                 1 cpu-migrations            #    0.002 M/sec                  
               116 page-faults               #    0.198 M/sec                  
          7,35,790 cycles                    #    1.255 GHz                     [81.06%]
     <not counted> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
     <not counted> instructions            
     <not counted> branches                
     <not counted> branch-misses           
   <not supported> L1-dcache-loads:HG      
     <not counted> L1-dcache-load-misses:HG
     <not counted> LLC-loads:HG            
   <not supported> LLC-load-misses:HG      

       0.088013919 seconds time elapsed
```

I read why `<not supported>` will show up from [`<not supported>`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98641/understanding-perf-tool-output). But I am getting `<not counted>` for even basic counters like instructions, branches etc. Can anyone suggest how to make it work?

Interesting thing is:

> sudo perf stat sleep 3

gives output:

```
Performance counter stats for 'sleep 3':

          0.598484 task-clock (msec)         #    0.000 CPUs utilized          
                 2 context-switches          #    0.003 M/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               181 page-faults               #    0.302 M/sec                  
     <not counted> cycles                  
     <not counted> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
     <not counted> instructions            
     <not counted> branches                
     <not counted> branch-misses
```

> sudo perf stat -C 1 sleep 3

```
 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 1':

       3002.640578 task-clock (msec)         #    1.001 CPUs utilized           [100.00%]
               425 context-switches          #    0.142 K/sec                   [100.00%]
                 9 cpu-migrations            #    0.003 K/sec                   [100.00%]
                 5 page-faults               #    0.002 K/sec                  
       7,82,97,019 cycles                    #    0.026 GHz                     [33.32%]
       9,38,21,585 stalled-cycles-frontend   #  119.83% frontend cycles idle    [33.32%]
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
       3,09,81,643 instructions              #    0.40  insns per cycle        
                                             #    3.03  stalled cycles per insn [33.32%]
         70,15,390 branches                  #    2.336 M/sec                   [33.32%]
          6,38,644 branch-misses             #    9.10% of all branches         [33.32%]

       3.001075650 seconds time elapsed
```

Why is this unexpected working.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processor does not support *so many counters* and *too frequent switching* between them, I guess.

You see in the last example the last column, where the counters are multiplexed (**counted only over 33% of the time**). If you use *small enough task* (or over more cores?), they are not counted, because all of the time the others were used. In your first example, only the `cycles` were managed to count in the time.

Comment: yes ,you are right @Jakuje . Such situation might be possible. But what you are saying is, as the executable file is small then it don't have sufficient time to multiplex events on the limited counters.

Comment: Not executable file, but execution time. Three seconds is really a little time.